# Problem running SBPL on ARM (Odroid-U3)

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, odroid, sbpl-lattice-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am facing a strange problem. I am using ROS move_base and SBPL for motion-primitive-based path planning.
I have generated some motion primitives for SBPL and everything works fine using my laptop (Intel i5, Ubuntu 14.04). The robot plans the path and moves fine along the path.

Now I am using the very same modules (and configs) on my Odroid U3 (ARM quadcore) and it cannot find a solution. Top shows that the core is at 100%. Here is the output from move_base

> [ INFO] [1412691428.999248673]: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"

> [ INFO] [1412691429.127272381]:     Subscribed to Topics:

> [ INFO] [1412691429.172789423]: Using plugin "inflation_layer"

> [ INFO] [1412691429.443358089]: Name is SBPLLatticePlanner

> [ INFO] [1412691430.931921673]: Planning with ARA*

> [ INFO] [1412691430.932365757]: [sbpl_lattice_planner] Initialized successfully

> [ INFO] [1412691430.989290632]: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"

> [ INFO] [1412691431.241103424]:     Subscribed to Topics:

> [ INFO] [1412691431.286346674]: Using plugin "inflation_layer"

> [ INFO] [1412691431.688199674]: Created local_planner base_local_planner/TrajectoryPlannerROS

> [ INFO] [1412691431.732307049]: Sim period is set to 0.10

> [ INFO] [1412691432.897083008]: odom received!

> [ INFO] [1412691492.209781994]: [sbpl_lattice_planner] getting start point (3.48925,-0.84064) goal point
> (2.00517,-1.3133)
> [ INFO] [1412691502.490063749]: Solution not found

> [ WARN] [1412691502.492333249]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 2.0000Hz... the loop actually took
> 10.0025 seconds

> [ INFO] [1412691502.492543791]: [sbpl_lattice_planner] getting start point (3.48925,-0.84064) goal point (2.00517,-1.3133)

> [ INFO] [1412691512.771037004]: Solution not found

I am using the following repos of the modules:

ROS indigo

sbpl_lattice_planner: https://github.com/meyerj/sbpl_lattice_planner.git

sbpl: https://github.com/sbpl/sbpl.git

Any ideas? I actually have no Idea where to start looking.

Cheers,

Markus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194392/problem-running-sbpl-on-arm-(odroid-u3)/) by [Markus Eich](https://answers.ros.org/users/1686/markus-eich/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2014-10-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is the ambiguity of the char datatype. On x86 gcc it defaults to signed, on ARM to unsigned. This results in negative values getting flipped.

See here: http://www.arm.linux.org.uk/docs/faqs/signedchar.php

and here: https://github.com/sbpl/sbpl/blob/master/src/include/sbpl/discrete_space_information/environment_navxythetalat.h#L61

one solution is to simply compile with the `-fsigned-char` switch, forcing all chars to be signed

```
## Compiler flags
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
    ## signed char is default on x86 gcc, not on arm however.
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fsigned-char")        
endif()
```

---

Originally posted by [philipp.schmutz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21558/philipp.schmutz/) with karma: 56 on 2015-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [philipp.schmutz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21558/philipp.schmutz/) on 2015-02-16**:
https://github.com/sbpl/sbpl/pull/27

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general, this error means that SBPL timed out before it could find a path connecting that start and goal points.

There are a few things you can try (in order from easiest to hardest):

- Make sure SBPL and sbpl_lattice_planner are compiled in release mode ( `catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` )
- Increase the global planner timeout
- Decrease the global costmap resolution
- Decrease the number of SBPL primitives

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus Eich](https://answers.ros.org/users/1686/markus-eich/) on 2014-10-09**:
This does not seem to help much.

- compiling with release did not improve the issue
- Set Global planner time out to 10 seconds. still no result
- I have set the resolution to 10cm. Still no solution

Decreasing the number of primitives is where I am currently stuck.

**Comment by [Markus Eich](https://answers.ros.org/users/1686/markus-eich/) on 2014-10-09**:
I am using the genprim_unicylce method. When I set the numberofangles=8, I can generate the primitives but the planner simply crashes.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-09**:
You may want to try choosing a goal point that's closer or further away from the robot.